# Getting Key-Value from Dynamic JSON Structure Scheme in asp.net core2 application

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I'm searching a proper way to read my appsettings.json file in asp.net core 2 application. I'm sharing my appsettings file.

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "IncludeScopes": false,
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Debug",
      "System": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Information"
    }
  },
  "Profiles": {
    "PROFILE1": {
      "Type": "AWS AssumeRole Credential",
      "RoleArn": "arn:aws:iam::11111111111111:role/CrossRole"
    },
    "PROFILE2": {
      "Type": "AWS InstanceProfile Credential",
      "RoleArn": "arn:aws:iam::000000000000:role/Role"
    },
    "AWS_DEBUG": {
      "Type": "AWS Credential MOCK",
      "MockProfile": "PROFILE1",
      "AccessKey": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
      "SecretKey": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    }
  }
}
```

The problem is that i want to retrieve all of the profile names and later then i will look at their "Type" property and will understand what other properties it has to be. So i can manage this dynamic json structure scheme in my code base.

My Web Application Startup script is setting configurations with IConfiguration object and I'm using it to access the json.

```
       public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }
```

I could use configuration["Profiles:PROFILE_SCHEME_1:Type"] to retrieve the values but i want to get these profile names, so the user can change the profile names without a problem. Is there a way to do "foreach profileName in ProfilesSection) and after then i have to retrieve that section to process. what is the best approach for that?

Comment: you dont store data that changes frequently in appsettings

Comment: I think you should store your profiles in database

Comment: Hello, The data will be static. I said dynamic structure because each profile has different scheme which is changing by Type property. I will edit my question to be clear about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```cs
var profiles = Configuration.GetSection("Profiles").GetChildren();
```

And then, for example, we can obtain the keys:

```cs
var profilesKeys = profiles.Select(p=>p.Key);
```

The types of the profiles you can obtain as follows:

```cs
var profilesTypes = profiles.Select(p => p["Type"]);
```

Comment: Thank you Alexandr. I got your idea and it works. I changed a little bit to succeed what i need.

My final code is like that:
var _profilesArray = _profiles.Select(p =>  new  { Key = p.Key, Type = p["Type"]  });